# Получение текущей раскладки

Tags: c++

Мне нужно получить текущую раскладку, этот код выводит всё правильно, но не выводит новую/переключённую раскладку

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (1) 
    {
        std::cout << GetKeyboardLayout(GetCurrentThreadId());
        Sleep(2000);
    }
}

//en 04090409 
//ru 04190419
```

Comment: Он выводит раскладку к того треда, у которого вы запрашиваете. Чтобы выудить раскладку текущего треда, надо найти окно, которое сейчас в фокусе, а потом найти поток, который это окно обслуживает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл решение и пришёл к `GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL))`
она выводит ID раскладки активного на данный момент окна, чтобы он работал, нужно в Visual Studio переключить с (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) на Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) дальше нужно вместо

```
int main(){
//Ваша программа
}
```

использовать

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow) {
//Ваша программа
}
```

лично эта main функция выключает всё GUI

все другие способы не работают с консольным приложением

Пример:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{
    while (1) {
        Sleep(2000);
                   //Задержка на 2сек 

        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("C:\\Users\\nuub228\\Desktop\\file.txt", ios::app);
                  //открытие файла в режиме записи

        fout << GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL));
                  //собственно запись ID раскладки

        fout.close();
                  //закрытие файла
    }
}
//ID раскладок
//ENG = 04090409
//RU == 04190419
```

Comment: А если в консольном приложении написать `GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(NULL, NULL));` - так не работает?

Comment: @Mikhailo тебе просто не выведет значение, потому что он не получить айди активного окна